# Clarify usage of the [robot] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robot) tag, which is intended to be used for "Questions related to **physical** robots". However, the tag is often used for questions about

- [robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robots.txt)
- [awtrobot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awtrobot)
- [robotframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robotframework)

which have no relation to physical robots.

I usually fix new questions that misuse the [robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robot) tag, but I wonder if there is an easy way how we could make the meaning of this tag more clear so that the questioners choose the correct tag in the first place.

Comment: That tag wiki is just wrong, it implicitly says that [robot] is off topic on SO and should never be used.  That's not the point of tags.  You can edit it.

Comment: I don't think that questions related to robots are off topic in general. There can be on topic programming-related questions in the context of robotics (e.g. about some library). But I agree that many of the questions tagged with [robot] would better fit to http://robotics.stackexchange.com/.